# How to autocomplete hashed known hosts with zsh

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, zsh

I am trying to figure out, how to auto complete known hosts from `.ssh/known_hosts`, with **zsh** when they are **hashed** (`.ssh/config` enabled `HashKnownHosts yes`) so I can type `ssh -l user host`.

Does anyone has an idea? I didn't find anything in the man pages or in the documentation.

Best and thanks,

A. Brose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Hash function is one-way function designed to be non-reversable. The most reasonable way is to configure your `~/.ssh/config` to `HashKnownHosts no`. There is no good reason to the hashing today, if you don't use some [old Debian](https://github.com/g0tmi1k/debian-ssh).

Comment: This is a very unclear answer. "There is no good reason to **that** today". No reason to do what today?

Comment: Sorry. To do the hashing indeed. Hopefully it is more clear now.